# How can I trim strings down to the first occurrence of a "；" or a "["

Tags: c#, regex

I have c# strings that look like this:

```
"かたむく；かたぶく[ok]"
"そば[側,傍]；そく[側]；はた"
"くすり"
"おととい[gikun]；おとつい[gikun]；いっさくじつ"
```

How can I trim these down so that the output has only text up to the first occurrence of a "；" character (not a normal semicolon) or a "[" or  if neither are present then the new string would be the same as the existing.

```
"かたむく"
"そば"
"くすり"
"おととい"
```

Is that something that would be best done with Regex or should I use some indexOf type of code to do this?

Comment: What have you tried, what's not working? I'm sure we'll help and provide a solution when you show us your attempt.

Comment: Code like `return "かたむく"` does exactly what you ask. If that's not correct you need to explain how you want to “trim” these strings.

Comment: `IndexOf` can be used to find the first index of the `[` character, and `Substring` can return the string up to that point.

Comment: Use string methods.  Get indexof("[") then use substring(startindex) to return character after the bracket.

Comment: Your input and expected output doesn't quite match. `かたむく；` doesn't have a space before the `;`. Also are you talking about the regular 'half width' space or a 'full width' space? If you want both, you'd have to alter the code accordingly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the comments. I now realize it's not a space followed by a semicolon. It's a "；" character

Comment: Yes, if you're not familiar with Japanese, there are two types of character sets. Full-width and half-width. You might want to read up a little bit about `Shift JIS`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209766/ansi-vs-shift-jis-vs-utf-8-in-c-sharp
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57142760/check-if-a-string-is-half-width-or-full-width-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Alan2 You do realize that `；` is still a character like the space and the `[`, right? It requires no special treatment. So, what exactly isn't clear about the answers you received so far?

Comment: I really don't understand the answers to be honest. The OP hasn't showed us anything, but we flock at throwing opinionated answer's around. We don't know what the OP is working with, so how can we correctly determine any of these actually fit into what the OP is working with? Just my opinion and thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `Regex`, just `string.IndexOfAny`.  Something like:

```
 var inputs = new[]
 {
     "かたむく；かたぶく[ok]",
     "そば[側,傍]；そく[側]；はた",
     "くすり",
     "おととい[gikun]；おとつい[gikun]；いっさくじつ"
 };

 var separators = new[] {' ', '['};

 foreach (var input in inputs)
 {
     var separatorPosition = input.IndexOfAny(separators);
     if (separatorPosition >= 0)
     {
         Debug.WriteLine($"Split: {input.Substring(0, separatorPosition)}");
     }
     else
     {
         Debug.WriteLine($"No Split: {input}");
     }

 }
```

I get the following output from your inputs:

```
Split: かたむく；かたぶく
Split: そば
No Split: くすり
Split: おととい
```

It doesn't quite match what you show, but I think it's correct (and what you show isn't)

Comment: Hi, can you clarify which is not correct. I need for your first example just to see "かたむく"

Comment: The first one, you split on the thing that looks like a colon (i.e., ending on the character that looks like less than).  I don't

Comment: Instead of using `IndexOfAny`, you could use `Split` which would do the trick and would be more concise. `foreach (var input in inputs){ Debug.WriteLine(input.Split(separators).First()); }`.

Comment: Oh I see now what you mean, it's a "；" character

Comment: @Alan2 If you want to split using `；` instead of a space character, then use that character in the `separators` array. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment, *"`IndexOf` can be used to find the first index of the `[` character, and `Substring` can return the string up to that point."*

```
public static string GetSubstringToChar(string input, char delimeter = '[')
{
    if (input == null || !input.Contains(delimeter)) return input;
    return input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf(delimeter));
}
```

To make this work with multiple delimeters, we can pass in an array of delimeter characters and use `IndexOfAny`:

```
public static string GetSubstringToChar(string input, char[] delimeters)
{
    if (input == null || !input.Any(delimeters.Contains)) return input;
    return input.Substring(0, input.IndexOfAny(delimeters));
}
```

You could then call this like:

```
var strings = new List<string>
{
    "かたむく；かたぶく[ok]",
    "そば[側,傍]；そく[側]；はた",
    "くすり",
    "おととい[gikun]；おとつい[gikun]；いっさくじつ",
};

var delimeters = new[] { '；', '[' };

foreach (var str in strings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetSubstringToChar(str, delimeters));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, How  can I also make the "；" as a deliminator so it works  for either "[" or "；"

Comment: You can use `IndexOfAny` with an array of characters. I've updated the example code.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't hear about IndexOfAny before.  I think that's very useful.

Answer (score 1):

An extension method with a little validation will do the job.

```
public static string GetUntil(this string input, char[] delimiters)
{
   if (input == null || input.IndexOfAny(delimiters) == -1)
      return input;
   else
      return input.Split(delimiters)[0];
}
```

then call like:

```
var test = "かたむく；かたぶく[ok]".GetUntil(new char[] { ' ', '[' });
```

Comment: The `IndexOfAny` check is redundant. You can safely get rid of it because `Split` would return the entire string if none of the delimiters is found.

Comment: Also, IMO, an extension method that returns null if the caller is null isn't a good practice. I would let the `NullReferenceException` do its job.

Comment: My reasoning for 'IndexOfAny' was to improve performance over the split operation.